# Error download using pop3 c#:Mediatype must be in the format type \"/\" subtype\r\nombre del parámetro: mediaType

Tags: c#, visual-studio, email, ssl

Estoy intentado obtener un email con adjunto de una casilla de correo usando pop3,el error se produce cuando obtengo el mensaje ¿alguien sabe por qué esto ocurre?. Solo pasa con alguno correos.

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= cantidadMesajes; i++)
 {
   mensaje = client.GetMessage(i);
 }
```

Error:

> Message: Media Type must be in the format type "/" subtype
>
> nombre del parámetro: mediaType

Comment: Estás definiendo el `MediaType` en algún sitio? Por cierto, estás usando algun librería en concreto para pop3?

Comment: No he definido el MediaType en ningún lado, no sé cómo definirlo, en cuanto a la librería estoy utilizado http://hpop.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Segun veo hay un [issue abierto sobre ese tema](https://github.com/foens/hpop/issues/44) desde 2015. Yo que tu trataría de buscar otra librería para pop3, ya que esa parece bastante abandonada...